# How do you approximate synchronous programming in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've read through all sorts of posts on this site as well as various articles and blogs on how one calls URLs using Node.js, but as this is my first Node project, the mental transition to asynchronous is eluding me. :-\

I'm trying to call an API with this simple code:

```
    var rp = require('request-promise');

    var options = {
       method: 'POST',
       strictSSL: false,
       headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
       uri: <URL goes here>,
       body: <body goes here>,
       json: true
    };

    rp(options)
       .then((res) => {
          let myToken = res['token'];
          console.log(myToken);
       })
       .catch((err) => {
          console.error('Returned: '+err);
       });
```

I am getting the correct response from the API and am able to parse out the value for 'token'.  However, where I'm hitting a mental block is how I then am able to use the value in myToken beyond the scope of the rp() call.

I understand the general model in Node/JavaScript is to use callbacks to continue processing once an asynchronous action completes, but if you have lots of other work to do (in my case, I anticipate calling a number of other APIs in sequence), how do you avoid having callbacks within callbacks within callbacks, etc. (what I believe is referred to as "callback hell")?

I've seen posts suggesting using fetch with await inside of an asynch body, but I cannot seem to return the value I need (in my example, the value of myToken); instead I just seem to return a Promise object.  The problem is that most examples I find just do a console.log() inside the callback with the key data, and never pass it back somewhere else.

If there are any better examples out there to which someone can refer me, it would be a huge help!  Thanks in advance.

Any

Comment: You're using Node? Or is this client side JS?

Comment: I mean, in the end you will always have callbacks in callbacks in callbacks, but there's certainly ways you can hide that fact such as using async/await, promises, and/or named functions.

Comment: You don't approximate synchronous programming.  Using `async/await` you can write code that sort of looks like synchronous code, but you still have to be fully  aware of the behaviors of asynchronous programming.

Comment: You USE the value inside the `.then()` handler or in some function you call from inside there (and pass the value  to).  That's how asynchronous programming works in Javascript.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin - It is pretty  clear from both  the tags and from the `require('request-promise'` that this is inside of node.js.  But, the answer doesn't actually matter since asynchronous programming in Javascript is the same in the browser or in node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 it wasn't there when the question was first asked. I provided an answer with async/await so if I had to I was going to mention bundling considering they are new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of asynchronous calls you can't really take the data from the response outside of the .then() of a Promise. However, If you just want all of your requests to happen at the same time (don't need to wait for one to finish) you can use Promise.all().

Say you have 3 requests you wish to make at the same time you would use code somewhat like this:

```js
const request1 = rp(options1);
const request2 = rp(options2);
const request3 = rp(options3);

Promise.all([request1, request2, request3]).then(values => {
    // [response1, response2, response3]
});
```

Unfortunately if you need data from the previous request in the next request the only way to avoid callbacks or promises is to await the request like so:

```js
async function requests() {
    const request1 = await rp(options1);
    const request2 = await rp(options2);
    const request3 = await rp(options3);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your multiple-await-statements-within-asynch-function is similar to Sankhavaram's suggestion below, and I think this may be what I'm looking for if, in fact, it allows you to ensure a previous statement completes before subsequent ones execute (because I do need information returned from earlier API calls to use in later ones).  Will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be concerned about preventing nested callbacks, which is good. You can do so by leveraging the fact that `then` and other Promise methods will return promises, ie:

```js
const tokenPromise = rp(options)
.then((res) => {
  let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
  const myToken = jsonObj['token'];
  return myToken;
})
.then((myToken) => {
  return doSomethingElse(myToken);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('Returned: '+err);
});

const doSomethingElse = (myToken) => {
  ...
}
```

In this example, if there is no error on the request, `doSomethingElse` could return a value, in which case `tokenPromise` would resolve with that value. Or, it could return a promise, and `tokenPromise` would resolve/reject based on that promise. I'd suggest looking at [bluebird's documentation, specifically "Why Promises",for an even better example.](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html).

You can't really access `myToken` outside of the context of the promise, but you can reuse the promise (you could store it as a global variable and check whether it has a value when you want to use it, but don't do that). Say you have another request that needs the value of `myToken` but is triggered elsewhere:

```
const doSomethingLater = () => {
  return tokenPromise.then((myToken) => {
    console.log(myToken);
  });
};
```

Calling `doSomethingLater` before the token request resolves would cause it to wait for the request, calling it after it has already resolved will result in `tokenPromise` resolving "immediately" with `myToken`.

If the token request is also triggered elsewhere (you don't make it immediately), and a method like `doSomethingLater` needs to be able to also trigger it if necessary, you could use a promise.

```
const _tokenPromise = null; // Should only be used in makeTokenRequest
const makeTokenRequest = () => {
  if (_tokenPromise) {
    return _tokenPromise;
  };

  _tokenPromise = rp(options)
  .then((res) => {
    let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
    const myToken = jsonObj['token'];
    return myToken;
  })
  .then((myToken) => {
    return doSomethingElse(myToken);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    //set _tokenPromise to null to retry on next call, you'd want better error handling irl
    _tokenPromise = null;
    console.error('Returned: '+err);
  });

  return _tokenPromise;
}

...

const doSomethingLater = () => {
  return makeTokenRequest().then((myToken) => {
    console.log(myToken);
  });
};
```

This way when `doSomethingLater` is triggered, it can make the token request if necessary, or reuse the one that is already in progress or has already resolved.  Note that in the catch, `_tokenPromise` is set to null, so that a failed call can be retried, in the real world you'd want better error handling than just this.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Hello,

    Here is a small example on how you can do subsequent API calls.

    const rp = require('request-promise');

    async function multipleCalls(){
    let firstCall = await rp(options1); //Waits until API call is done
    console.log(firstCall['token']) //You can use the token for later calls if needed.
    let secondCall = await rp(options2); //Waits until API Call is done
    console.log("You can call any number of API calls this way");
    }

Hope this helps!
```

Comment: In your example, it seems like using multiple await statements within an asynch function *is* sort of approximating synchronous flow if nothing happens until after the "let firstCall ..." statement completes.  Did I understand your "Waits until API call is done" correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic example of how you can get the token and use it, using async/await. You can only await functions that return promises and async and await can only be used in the scope of a function.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function fetchToken() {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    strictSSL: false,
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
    uri: '',
    body: '',
    json: true,
  };

  // error handling for await function
  try {
    await rp(options)
    .then((res) => {
      let myToken = res['token'];
      return myToken;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Returned: '+err);
      return err;
    });
  } catch(err) {
    // catch try block error
    return err;
  }
}


async function doWhateverWithToken() {
  const token = await fetchToken();
  // use token / store token / do whatever with it
  // check if token is an error
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I copied your example above into a .js file and amended it as such:
1) added a call to doWhateverWithToken(); to actually run it (which I think I needed)
2) added console.log('token: '+token); right after the call to fetchToken() in doWhateverWithToken.

I expected the output to be what was parsed from the API response, but instead I got:

"token: undefined"

Should doWhateverWithToken() be invoked differently?

Comment: This --> `console.log('token: '+token)` looks incorrect. You dont need the '+'. A comma will do in console log to separate parameters. console.log('token: ', token)